# Allegro library missing dll

Tags: c++, dll, allegro

I have installed allegro 5.0.8 version on visual c++2010 express . But now when I run the code it doesn't give any syntax errors but after opening the console a window opens which reports that I don't have MSVCR110d.dll file . What it means ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Microsoft C++ Redistributable package for both 32 and 64 bit

32: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555
64: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632