# MSCVR110d.dll Missing in Allegro / VS Set Up

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, allegro, allegro5

So I'm trying to set up an Allegro template by linking everything to a new VS program.

I've downloaded the `.cc` files from [Allegro](https://www.allegro.cc/files/) and followed the installation guide in it's [Wiki](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5) for setting up with Visual Studio 2010.

The version is `5.0.10`.

Upon putting the `main` source code in my first program and linking everything as per the wiki (`bin, include, lib`), the program builds fine, however, when you go to debug/run the program in VS, a window pops up with:

```
This program can't run because msvcr110d.dll missing from your computer.
```

I'm successfully tested other VS projects using other third party libraries and they still work fine.

What could be the problem?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741801/allegro-library-missing-dll) S/O question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: That's the debug runtime for VS2012. Any idea why the program links to that?

Answer (score 0):

You may download and install the MSVC redistributable: http://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Anyway, it's not normal that msvcr110d is required instead of msvcr110. That means that the library you are using has been compiled with the debug runtime of the MSVC2012. Check it and choose the right library files.

Comment: Do you refer my first sentence? you need to choose the right .lib file. Link to mt/md depending on your compiler (properties, c/c++, code generation), and do not choose ...-debug.lib since it will ask you for the debug MSVC runtime dll.

Comment: @DídacPérez The tutorial he follows includes ready made .lib files that link to the debug runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following includes this text:

> This tutorial may reference an older version number than what is available on that page. While following the instructions, if you copy and paste something with a version number, be sure to update it to reflect the version you downloaded.

That would indeed appear to be the case. The runtime that the program is trying to link to is the runtime for VS2012. So it seems that the files you downloaded are more recent than the tutorial. The .lib files that you are using are linked against VS2012.

Possible solutions:

1. Repeat the steps in the tutorial, but use VS2012 rather than VS2010.
2. Find the old version of the tutorial that has VS2010 .lib files.
3. Build the entire thing from scratch so that you are not dependent on supplied .lib files that are tied to a specific version of VS.

Comment: The visual studio program runs okay in a `Release` version, but not a `Debug` version...

Comment: That's because you have the VS2012 runtime installed on your machine. The runtime you are linking to that gives the error is the debug runtime for VS2012. You have not got that. You've got a bunch of .lib files, pre-complied for you, that link against VS2012 runtime. Pick one of the three steps from my answer.